# UI Panel object changes position after running scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently am doing following scene: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFqBO.png

Which has the white panel displayed. The panel is the child of a canvas, which is the child of the camera. Because of this the panel should stay at the position relative to the camera, which it does. However, I have a scene where the camera movies quite a bit, and when I stop the scene, the position of the panel is displaced from the camera:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M2Mh.png

It moves further and further back the more times I run the scene. I've never seen anything like this, as I would believe the whole scene would return to default after the scene is stopped. What's going on?

Edit: Added new images as SO's system didn't seem to work atm.

Edit2: Should be noted the issue is inconsistent. I run the same scene through (doing the exact same thing every time), and sometime it simply misplaces itself.

Edit3: Adding my main script of the scene, which control all movement.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class IntroManuscript : MonoBehaviour {

    //Initializing outside gameObjects & scripts
    public GameObject spotWindow, structure, monster, spot_Wheelchair, wheelchair, snd_Door, theCamera,
        wheelchairMovingSound, spot_Doll, dollModel, doll_Rigid, dollSpot_spark, car, flashFade;

    public PathLines pathLines;

    //Properties for external objects & scripts
    public float monsterSpeed, wheelchairSpeed, shockPower, deAcceleration,
        dollPushPower, rotateSpeed, carSpeed;

    //Activate the string that matches the next segment
    string steps = "beginning", movingTo = "moveBeginning";

    //Add external scripts
    public Wheelchair wchair;

    //Add audioclips for several audio clips per AudioSource
    public AudioClip snd_wheelchairCol;

    //Bools
    bool playerMoving = false;
    bool playOnce = true;
    bool pushOnce = true;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(stepDecider());       
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate() {
        switch(steps)
        {
            case "beginning":
                break;
            case "windowOn":
                spotWindow.SetActive(true);              
                break;
            case "monsterWalk":
                monster.SetActive(true);
                monster.transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * monsterSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                break;
            case "monsterPassedWindow":
                Destroy(spotWindow);
                Destroy(monster);
                Destroy(structure);
                break;
            case "doorOpen":
                snd_Door.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case "firstSpotlightOn":
                spot_Wheelchair.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case "dropWheelchair":
                wheelchair.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case "secondSpotlightOn":
                spot_Doll.SetActive(true);
                break;
            case "dollEntrance":
                if(pushOnce == true)
                {
                    dollModel.SetActive(true);
                    doll_Rigid.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(-transform.right * dollPushPower, ForceMode.Impulse);
                    pushOnce = false;
                }
                break;
            case "secondSpotlightBreak":
                if(dollModel == null)
                {
                    if(spot_Doll.GetComponent<Light>().enabled == true)
                    {
                        Destroy(spot_Doll);
                        dollSpot_spark.SetActive(true);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "carEntrance":
                car.SetActive(true);      
                break;
            case "carMove":
                if(Vector3.Distance(car.transform.position, theCamera.transform.position) > 10)
                {
                    car.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(car.transform.position, theCamera.transform.position, carSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                    flashFade.SetActive(true);
                }
                break;
            case "changeScene":
                SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
                break;
        }

        switch(movingTo)
        {
            case "moveBeginning":
                break;
            case "firstSpotlight":
                if(wchair.wheelchairCollided == false) 
                {
                    theCamera.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(theCamera.transform.position, pathLines.pathPoints[1].transform.position, wheelchairSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                    playerMoving = true;
                } else
                {                 
                    if(playOnce == true)
                    {
                        wheelchair.GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = snd_wheelchairCol;
                        wheelchair.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
                        playOnce = false;
                    }
                    theCamera.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(theCamera.transform.position, new Vector3(theCamera.transform.position.x, theCamera.transform.position.y, -6f), shockPower * Time.deltaTime);
                    if(shockPower > 0)
                    {
                        shockPower -= deAcceleration;                      
                    }
                    playerMoving = false;
                }
                break;
            case "secondSpotlightRotating":
                theCamera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.RotateTowards(theCamera.transform.forward, pathLines.pathPoints[2].transform.position - theCamera.transform.position, rotateSpeed, 0.0f));
                break;
            case "secondSpotlightMoving":
                theCamera.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(theCamera.transform.position, pathLines.pathPoints[2].transform.position, wheelchairSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                if(theCamera.transform.position == new Vector3(-1.7f, 1.73f, 7.5f))
                {
                    if(spot_Doll.GetComponent<Light>().enabled == false)
                    {
                        Destroy(dollModel);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        if(playerMoving == true)
        {
            if(wheelchairMovingSound.GetComponent<AudioSource>().isPlaying == false)
            {
                wheelchairMovingSound.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
            } 
        } else
        {
            wheelchairMovingSound.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Stop();
        }
    }

    //Assigning second floats, initialize and tweak through inspector
    public float sec_windowOn, sec_monsterWalk, sec_monsterPassedWindow, sec_doorOpen, sec_firstSpotlightOn,
        sec_moveFirstSpotlight, sec_dropWheelchair, sec_secondSpotlightOn, sec_dollEntrance, sec_rotateSecondSpotlight,
        sec_moveSecondSpotlight, sec_secondSpotlightBreak, sec_carEntrance, sec_carMove, sec_changeScene;

    IEnumerator stepDecider()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec_windowOn);
        steps = "windowOn";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec_monsterWalk);
        steps = "monsterWalk";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec_monsterPassedWindow);
        steps = "monsterPassedWindow";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec_doorOpen);
        steps = "doorOpen";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec_firstSpotlightOn);
        steps = "firstSpotlightOn";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec_moveFirstSpotlight);
        movingTo = "firstSpotlight";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec_dropWheelchair);
        steps = "dropWheelchair";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec_secondSpotlightOn);
        steps = "secondSpotlightOn";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec_dollEntrance);
        steps = "dollEntrance";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec_rotateSecondSpotlight);
        movingTo = "secondSpotlightRotating";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec_moveSecondSpotlight);
        movingTo = "secondSpotlightMoving";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec_secondSpotlightBreak);
        steps = "secondSpotlightBreak";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec_carEntrance);
        steps = "carEntrance";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec_carMove);
        steps = "carMove";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec_changeScene);
        steps = "changeScene";
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any code we can look into?

Comment: @timostevens Added my main script of the scene (The rest are light flickerings etc.). That script controls the camera and mainly handles everything. For the panel itself I'm just using an animation to create a transition.

Comment: I guess making your Canvas's space to World will fix the problem. https://images.contentful.com/hcpes7ygcu3i/4olO6F9pKUkSEOEW6Mc8K2/302c745ce53f2c4723d9cb580048fac8/UnityExtension-CanvasInspector.png

Comment: @ZayedUpal It seem to have. Such a simple fix, thank you.